# Untrack a file and gitignore it but dont delete it on the server when pulling

Tags: git

I created a project and tracked configuration files. Now i want to remove them from being tracked and from the repo.

So i put them in the .gitignore. Then i did `git rm -cached` with these files. I committed it but now what happens if i pull this branch is that on the remote it deletes all these files on the server.

Thats not what i want. It should maintain the files locally and also remotely but the files should not be tracked or appear in the repo. Is that possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, that isn't possible.

You can either have the file in the Git repository and have it be tracked, or not have it in the Git repository and be untracked.  To track a file means to have it in the repository.  If you delete a file from the repository and ignore it, it is untracked and is no longer a part of the repository.

If your goal is to take a file in the repo and ignore changes to it, the best way to do that is to create some sort of template file that *is* tracked and copy it into place of the untracked file you want to modify.  This can be done by hand or by a build or setup script of some sort.

There are people who will tell you to use the skip-worktree or assume-unchanged bits for this, but that is not supported and the [Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_notes) says not to do this.